# System Policy won't let me install TurboTax

Tags: windows-7, group-policy

I was just given a new computer with Windows 7 at work because my old one died . Now when I try to install my tax software which I really need it says
"installation is forbidden by system policy. Contact your system administrator."
This is really annoying and I'm not very good with registry stuff.

Comment: Did you do what it says and talk to your system administrator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to edit the registry.

1. Hold down windows key and press 'R'
2. In the window that pops up type gpedit.msc and click ok
3. Navigate to Computer Configuration>Administrative Templates>Windows Components>Windows Installer.
4. Double-click 'Prohibit non-administrators from applying vendor signed updates'. Select disabled and click ok

Comment: Thanks that did it. The computer is from another company and we don't have an It department.

Comment: @user80063 - If that's the case then you should wipe and reinstall Windows, or you're probably going to keep bumping into this problem.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like this computer is owned by your place of business and administered by your IT staff, therefore they can decide what software can be installed on their machines. You will need to speak with them so they can either install the software for you, or will give you the privileges to install software.

Part of the IT department's role is to make sure employees have access to the technology resources they need; software is one of those resources. If there is a business need for you to have the software on your system, they should make sure the software is available to you. If they do not, then your route for appeal would be to speak with someone who can direct the IT staff that you have a business need for the software to be installed.

If the software is just for your personal needs and not for any business needs, of course you're free to make your case to the IT department and management, but more than likely they will ask you to install your personal software on your personal computer.

Comment: +1  Contact IT for this if it is company hardware.  Installing "unapproved" software is often a dicipline matter if caught.

Comment: Judging from a comment on another answer, it looks like I made an incorrect assumption about the structure and politics of your company. Nevertheless, many people will probably arrive on this page looking for ways around their IT department's policies, so I'll leave my answer for future visitors.

Comment: Agreed. Perhaps I should have waited for more info before posting. Hey 99 more to go until the sportsmans badge.